# word spacing changes in smaller viewports

Tags: html, web

I'm facing an issue regarding word-spacing that after a certain smaller viewport(after 700px), the word-spacing of some words changes and thus creates an overall weird look.

Code is given below the images:-(Only HTML as no CSS have been applied till now)

[image]

[image]

Code:-
**HTML:-**

```
<strong class="day">Day 06: Bikaner sightseeing</strong>
                <p class="day-detail">
                    After breakfast, we will start our day tour covering <b>Junagarh fort</b>-one of the famous forts of Bikaner,
                    also known as <i>"Chintamani"</i>, <b>Lalgarh palace</b>-another architectural marvel of Bikaner, this fort is
                    built using red sandstone.
                    Then we'll head on to visit <b>Camel farm</b>(Here we'll see lots of camels of varying breeds, this place is
                    also known as ICAR) and then come back to the hotel for overnight stay.</p>
               
 <strong class="day">Day 05: Jaisalmer- Bikaner</strong>
                    <p class="day-detail">
                        After having a toothsome breakfast at the hotel, drive to Bikaner. On the way visit <b>khichan village
                        Bird Sanctuary</b>(which is famous for being home to Demoiselle Cranes-locally known as kurja that migrate here
                        every winter), then after lunch, we'll continue our journey to Bikaner. Post arrival, check-in at the hotel then
                        relax.<br />
                        Overnight stay at the pre-booked hotel.</p>
                    </p>
```

Comment: that is a techincal downside of `text-align: justify` which will force the gaps to increase to fill the entire line to the very end. Properly the best then to change that property to `start`, `end` or `center`.

Comment: @tacoshy yes you're right and it worked but is there a way to justify the text and also not get the weird effect like the above one.

Comment: how is that suppose to work? You either want to spread the word to fill the entire line (justify) which will leave you with gaps or you dont want gaps but that means the word wont be spread to the end of the line. It's technical and logically not possible to get both as they contradict each other. Only thing you can try is to include word-breaks.